# C# database Merge/replication

Tags: c#, ms-access, merge, dataset, replication

I want to create a replication solution for my MS Access based application. I have 2-4 sites creating content into the database, and they are all offline. My Solution so far:

Function called from File menu:

```
class main
{
private void menuItemMergeUserData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openDataFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            openDataFileDialog.Title = "Select UserData file to merge";
            openDataFileDialog.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            openDataFileDialog.Filter = "Database files (*.mdb)|*.mdb|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openDataFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openDataFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ExternalUserManager UserManager = new ExternalUserManager(openDataFileDialog.FileName, CompanyID, dbManager);
                if (UserManager.MergeUserTables())
                    MessageBox.Show("UserData merged!", "UserData");
            }
            openDataFileDialog.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Function called in class ExternalUserManager

```
 public bool MergeUserTables()
        {
            bool bOk = true;

            try
            {
                //databaseManager.CallMacro(dbMyFileName);

                conUserData.Open();


                daClass.Fill(dsUserData, "Class");
                daClassUsers.Fill(dsUserData, "ClassUsers");
                daCompany.Fill(dsUserData, "Company");
                daCurriculum.Fill(dsUserData, "Curriculum");
                daCurriculumExercises.Fill(dsUserData, "CurriculumExercises");
                daCurriculumMissions.Fill(dsUserData, "CurriculumMissions");
                daCurriculumTasks.Fill(dsUserData, "CurriculumTasks");
                daUserModes.Fill(dsUserData, "UserModes");
                daUserProfile.Fill(dsUserData, "UserProfile");
                daUsers.Fill(dsUserData, "Users");
                bOk = databaseManager.MergeDataSet(dsUserData);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Reading UserData");
            }
            finally
            {
                conUserData.Close();
            }

            return bOk;
        }
```

function called in class DatabaseManager

```
public bool MergeDataSet(DataSetUserContent dsExternalUserContent)
        {
            bool bOk = false;
            try
            {

                this.dsUserContent.MergeFailed += new MergeFailedEventHandler(OnMergeFailed);
                this.dsUserContent.Merge(dsExternalUserContent);
                if(this.dsUserContent.HasChanges())
                    bOk = SaveUsers();
             }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "LogData Merge");
            }
            finally
            {
                conLogData.Close();
            }

            return bOk;
        }
```

**The DataSet is merged just as I want, however new rows from the imported database was not saved to database???**

Have search for solutions for this problem and [some say](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/datasetmerge.html) set AcceptChangesDuringFill = false . Tried it but this made all the rows from imported database be added as new rows in the source database.

Comment: ahh that reminds me 2004 a web service i developed for banking solutions... but not remember too much of it by now. Still would ask if you have proper primary keys setup in your DB and DS.

Answer (score 0):

If all the apps are offline, why don't you simply copy the mdb file over?

It's crude, I know, but it should work fine.